# Refactoring conditional logic in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am not sure whether I am trying to abstract too much in this code or there is a simpler way to what I am trying to do. Below is the code:

```
some_hash = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 } 
some_hash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
   if (index % 2 == 0)
      open_foo1
      open_foo2 # The order is important, that is why it has not been abstracted
   else
      open_foo2
   end
     close_foo1  # This is a bug what if foo1 was never opened, my other solution
                 # was to put it in the else clause but what if we never get there
     close_foo2
     # do something here that is applicable to both conditions
 end
```

So I came up with this but it just does not feel right.

```
 some_hash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
       if (index % 2 == 0)
          open_foo1
          open_foo2 # The order is important, that is why it has not been abstracted
       else
          open_foo2
       end
       if (index % 2 == 0)
         close_foo1
       end  
       close_foo2 #In the worst case foo2 would be opened
       # do something here that is applicable to both conditions
     end
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Now doesn't `if index.even?` look better than `if (index % 2 == 0)`?

Comment: syntatic sugar indeed! I like your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open_foo2` is called in both case; You can omit the first `else`.

Repeated predicate can be evaluated only once.

```
some_hash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
  foo1 = index % 2 == 0
  open_foo1 if foo1
  open_foo2
  close_foo1 if foo1
  close_foo2
end
```

Comment: Looks good +1 -- wouldn't this work too?: `foo1 ? open_foo1, close_foo1 : open_foo2, close_foo2`

Comment: @feed_me_code, It will cause `SyntaxError`. And it have different semantics.